# Unable to remove MySQL-server on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to reinstall mysql-server on Ubuntu, since I accidentely removed some users and now phpmyadmin doesn't seem to be working giving me `#1449 - The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist`. Because I removed mysql user and now I don't know how to recreate it with the password that only the system knows.

So, I decided to reinstall mysql. However, when I'm trying to remove it with command `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*` or similar it gives me these errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb'
E: Unable to locate package mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb'
E: Unable to locate package mysqlbinlog
```

Literally trying to resolve this for hours now with no luck. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to do it with:

```
sudo -i
service mysql stop
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client
apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
apt-get autoclean
deluser --remove-home mysql
delgroup mysql
rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql* /var/log/upstart/mysql.log* /var/run/mysqld
updatedb
exit
```